# How to have a custom route without parameter names in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have the following route to my method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Company/Employees/{name}")]
public ActionResult Details(string name)
```

I want to access the employee with a name property of "John" by making a request to

```
Company/Employees/John
```

But now the route only works if I type:

```
Company/Employees?name=John
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

This is my route config (inside an area)

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Company_default",
            "Company/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Employees", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "MySite.Areas.Company.Controllers" }
        );
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `{name}` part with `{id}` ?

Comment: @RosdiKasim - yeap, not working

Comment: It doesn't seem wrong to me, was there another actionresult that uses the same namespace?

Comment: @aeee98 - there are other methods in the same controller

Comment: Try changing both to `id` in the route and in the parameter variable name

Comment: I've already tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could be that your default routing mess all up. Can you shouw it? What's in your `RouteConfig`?

Comment: It should not be a problem but try to use `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]`. Just to give it a try.

Comment: @teovankot - I've pasted it in my question

Comment: @Yulian yeah, looks like this is an issue. Becouse your Default route have optional id at the end, when you post your url MVC uses befault route instead of yours.

Comment: @teovankot - so, do you have any ideas how to get this thing working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already say, your default route have same sturture as your custom Contoller Route. Becouse `{id}` param is **optional**.

If you want to use your route you should define custom route in your RouteConfig BEFORE your default route and get rid of your `Route` Attribute on controller:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "DetailsCustom",
            "Company/Employees/{name}",
            new { controller = "Employees", action = "Details"},
            namespaces: new[] { "MySite.Areas.Company.Controllers" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your other route:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "Company_default",
        "Company/{controller}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Employees", action = "Index", id =    UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "MySite.Areas.Company.Controllers" }
    );
```

as your previous one is picking up "John" as the "action" parameter